# Nested Terms Aggregation with sort on Sum Aggregation

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

There are bellow Nested class,

```
public class ServiceEntries
{  
    public string servicename{ get; set; }
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectT> projects { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectT
{
    public string project_engineer { get; set; }
    public decimal project_money { get; set; }
}
```

what I need is make a Term Aggregation by term of **project_engineer**, and order by the **Sum** the **project_money**,

I try to follow https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/aggregations/nested.html but somehow didn't make it out, not sure where to place the .Term Aggregation.

Please kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: What version of NEST and ES do you use?

Comment: ES: elasticsearch-1.7.2, NEST: 1.0.0 (I can upgrade NEST version for sure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using NEST 1.8.0 against Elasticsearch 1.7.4.

First things first, let's set up a ConnectionSettings that is going to allow use to see the requests and responses easily; I'm working in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) for this example so the output appears in the bottom pane when I execute

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
    .ExposeRawResponse(true)
    .PrettyJson()
    .SetDefaultIndex("entries")
    // Let's map the servicename as the id for ServiceEntries types
    .MapIdPropertyFor<ServiceEntries>(entry => entry.servicename)
    // This is good for the purposes of this demo, but we don't want 
    // to be doing logging **all** requests in production
    .SetConnectionStatusHandler(r =>
    {
        // log out the requests
        if (r.Request != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} \n{2}\n", r.RequestMethod.ToUpperInvariant(), r.RequestUrl,
                Encoding.UTF8.GetString(r.Request));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}\n", r.RequestMethod.ToUpperInvariant(), r.RequestUrl);
        }

        if (r.ResponseRaw != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}\n{1}\n\n{2}\n", r.HttpStatusCode, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(r.ResponseRaw), new String('-', 30));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}\n\n{1}\n", r.HttpStatusCode, new String('-', 30));
        }
    });

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Now we have a client to work with, we'll first need to create an index with a mapping suitable for the problem at hand

```
client.CreateIndex("entries", c => c
    .AddMapping<ServiceEntries>(m => m
        .Properties(p => p
            .String(s => s
                .Name(n => n.servicename)
                // No need to analyze the string id
                // on the POCO
                .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)
            )
            .NestedObject<ProjectT>(n => n
                .Name(nn => nn.projects.First())
                .MapFromAttributes()
                .Properties(pp => pp
                    .String(s => s
                        .Name(nn => nn.project_engineer)
                        // map engineer names as not analyzed so
                        // we have the raw values to aggregate on.
                        // If you also need to search on these, take a
                        // look at mapping as a multi_field
                        .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

With the index in place, let's generate some data to work with

```
var engineerNames = new[] { "Paul", "John", "Ringo", "George" };

var entries = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i =>
{
    var entry = new ServiceEntries()
    {
        servicename = i.ToString(),
        timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(i),
        projects = new List<UserQuery.ProjectT>
        {
            new UserQuery.ProjectT
            {
                project_engineer = engineerNames[i%4],
                project_money = i
            }
        }
    };

    return entry;
});

// bulk index all ServiceEntries and refresh the index after indexing
// so we can search on it immediately
client.Bulk(b => b.IndexMany(entries, (bd, d) => bd.Document(d)).Refresh());
```

***Now for the fun part!*** To perform aggregations on nested types, we first need to set up a [Nested Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) with a path that points to the nested type, then *nest* the Aggregations we want to perform on the nested type. Finally, we also want to [sort on the result of a sub aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/_sorting_based_on_deep_metrics.html).

```
var response = client.Search<ServiceEntries>(s => s
    .Size(0)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        // set up a nested aggregation
        .Nested("project",n => n
            // the path to the nested type
            .Path(entry => entry.projects)
            .Aggregations(aa => aa
                // aggregate by project engineer
                .Terms("project_engineers", t => t
                    .Field(entry => entry.projects.First().project_engineer)
                    // order project engineer names by the descending sum of project money
                    .OrderDescending("project_money.value")
                    .Aggregations(aaa => aaa
                        // sum project money for each project engineer
                        .Sum("project_money", sa => sa
                            .Field(entry => entry.projects.First().project_money)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This generates the following json

```
POST http://localhost:9200/entries/serviceentries/_search?pretty=true 
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "project": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "projects"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "project_engineers": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "projects.project_engineer",
            "order": {
              "project_money.value": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "project_money": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "projects.project_money"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and produces the following result

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 100,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "project" : {
      "doc_count" : 100,
      "project_engineers" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [ {
          "key" : "Paul",
          "doc_count" : 25,
          "project_money" : {
            "value" : 1300.0
          }
        }, {
          "key" : "George",
          "doc_count" : 25,
          "project_money" : {
            "value" : 1275.0
          }
        }, {
          "key" : "Ringo",
          "doc_count" : 25,
          "project_money" : {
            "value" : 1250.0
          }
        }, {
          "key" : "John",
          "doc_count" : 25,
          "project_money" : {
            "value" : 1225.0
          }
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You rocks Russ, and thanks for introduce me the  LinqPad.

Comment: hi Russ, how to make LINQPad work with ElasticSearch? I didn't see the relative Driver for LINQPad.

Comment: Use the in built nuget package manager and install the NEST package

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks

Comment: Hi Russ, may I ask a new question: how to make a Term Aggregation by term of *servicename*, and order by the Sum the project_money ?

Comment: well, as NEST don't support reversed nested yet: https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/aggregations/reverse-nested.html , seems I can't make it out

Comment: @rmrf100 that documentation is old. Reverse Nested Aggregation is supported in NEST 1.2.0 and above. I'd recommend upgrading to 1.8.0, the latest compatible with Elasticsearch 1,x and taking a look at - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/1.x/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Integration/Aggregations/NestedBucketAggregationTests.cs#L83

Comment: Thank you Russ, yes, I will give up that old document, and use elastic's official document.